# Workflow not firing off

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2016

I have a workflow that sends an email when a field is set to “yes” in an infopath form. The workflow itself just says if fieldx=yes then send email. But workflow did not fire. The field has “yes”, so it ahould have fired off but I cant find a logical reason why. Any way to check all the instances for a particular workflow or anything else i can investigate?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of workflow actions you used? That will help us to answer your question.

Comment: Are you testing with an admin account? Workflows will not auto fire for those.

Comment: Are you trying to do a manual workflow trigger? Or are you trying to have the workflow trigger on item creation? If so, make sure your workflow is set to automatically start on new items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger wf start when item is modified or created. Then as first action check the condition if the email is yes then send whatever comms you need if not just terminate the wf.